# Is Goldreich's proof with polynomial number of hybrid arguments wrong?

Tags: provable-security, terminology, security-definition

Oded Goldreich in his book [[Foundations of Cryptography](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/foc.html), 2004, Section 3.2.3] proves a theorem by polynomial number of hybrids.

---

[image]

---

In rather recent years, Marc Fischlin and Arno Mittelbach published a paper [FM21, [IACR 2021/088](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/088)] and prove lemma 3.1 (equivalent to Goldreich's above theorem) by first considering 4 types of hybrid arguments:

1-section 3.1 Constant Number of Hybrids,

2-section 3.2 Polynomial Number of Hybrids *with a Universal Distinguishing Bound*,

3-section 3.3 Polynomial Number of Hybrids: *Non-uniform Variant*,

4-section 3.4 Polynomial Number of Hybrids: *Uniform Variant*
(Goldreich proof is the item 2 of case 4)

**Goldreich doesn't mention these 3 type of polynomial number of hybrids at all** and prove the above theorem. *Does he overlook some important details and his proof need correction*?

I quote some lines from the paper:

> Our blunder on the presentation of the hybrid argument was a good reminder how easy it is to trip up on formalizing cryptography and how seemingly small details can have devastating effects. Yet, when researching the literature we found that we were in good company.

> ... is utterly wrong if one allows non-constant t. And yet, this statement not only appears on Wikipedia, but also in this form in many research papers and cryptographic lecture notes.

---

In the paper, a counter example has been presented:

---

[image]

---

Especially this part of Goldreich's proof in the following, is it correct?

> ...Because the total number of hybrids is polynomial in $n$, a non-negligible gap between (the “accepting” probability of $D$ on) the extreme hybrids translates into a non-negligible gap between (the “accepting” probability of D on) a pair of neighboring hybrids. ...

In the paper, Fischin and Mittelbach feel that we need some conditions and consider 4 types of hybrid arguments.

And here is Goldreich's proof:

### [image]

Comment: His proof predates the recent work  So, the new work may be a refinement of the model/proof method that he uses. What exactly are you asking? Do the authors of the recent work refer to his work? That's the natural direction one should look.

Comment: @kodlu, No they do not refer to prior works and state "Our blunder on the presentation of the hybrid argument was a good reminder how
easy it is to trip up on formalizing cryptography and how seemingly small details
can have devastating effects. Yet, when researching the literature we found that
we were in good company." ... " is utterly wrong1 if one allows non-constant t. And yet, this statement not only appears on Wikipedia, but also in this form in many research
papers and cryptographic lecture notes" I want to know if Goldreich's proof for this theorem misses something or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goldreich proves an "$m$-fold repetition" theorem: if $X \approx Y$ then $X^m = (X,X, \ldots, X) \approx Y^m = (Y,Y, \ldots, Y)$. In this setting, $m$ is an arbitrary polynomial function of the security parameter.

His reduction says, more or less: if $A$ can distinguish $X^m$ from $Y^m$, then consider $B$ which does the following on input $s$:

- sample $i$ uniformly from $\{1,\ldots,m\}$,
- sample $x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}$ from $X$,
- sample $y_{i+1}, \ldots, y_m$ from $Y$,
- give $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, s, y_{i+1}, \ldots, y_m)$ to $A$

He then argues that $B$'s advantage is $1/m$ times $A$'s advantage.

Observations:

1. The theorem Goldreich proves is not invalidated by Fischlin-Mittelbach. Indeed, they too use the $m$-fold repetition as a concrete running example for how their theorems work.
2. Goldreich proves it by a reduction algorithm that chooses the hybrid index $i$ uniformly. This is exactly one of the recipes that Fischlin-Mittelbach propose in section 3.4. The $B$ that I described is precisely the $B$ that they describe on page 19, where transformation $T$ is the obvious thing for a $m$-fold repetition.

Comment: I understand Goldreich's proof (I hope), as you wrote. Fischlin and Mittelbach consider 3 branches in for non-constant number of hybrids and then prove the theorem, whereas Goldreich doesn't. Indeed, one of their cases (section 3.4 Polynomial Number of Hybrids: Uniform Variant: theorem 3.8, number 2)  is exactly like the way Goldreich proves the theorem. What about other two and half cases which Goldreich doesn't consider? I want to use this theorem with its proof, so I need to know if this proof is complete or not?

Comment: Fischlin-Mittelbach are giving convenient general-purpose recipes for proving statements like "if $H_i \approx H_{i+1}$ then $H_0 \approx H_n$," for **totally arbitrary distributions** $H_i$. Goldreich is only proving "$m$-fold repetition," a special case where $H_i = (\underbrace{X, \ldots, X}_i, Y, \ldots, Y)$. [Actually his theorem statement only cares about proving that the endpoints $H_0$ and $H_m$ are indistinguishable.] You only need one of the Fischlin-Mittelbach recipes to prove this special case.

Comment: In summary, Goldreich proves "if $X \approx Y$ then $X^m \approx Y^m$", he proves it in maximum generality (i.e, for all $X,Y$). He does it by introducing a sequence of hybrids and reasoning about the hybrid argument in a way that is equivalent to one of the Fischlin-Mittelbach-approved methods. Fischlin-Mittelbach also give more methods, which can work even in other hybrid proofs.

Comment: Goldreich's theorem is equivalent to lemma 3.1 of Fischlin and Mittelbach's paper. To prove lemma 3.1 or Goldreich's theorem, it appears that hybrid arguments are used. However, *before proving this proposition*, the question arises: Did Goldreich overlook some important details while proving the theorem or lemma 3.1 in the paper using hybrid arguments? In other words, it seems that Goldreich's proof is not just a special case but an incomplete proof.

Comment: @user1035648, if you think that there is a gap, you should publish it (on IACR eprint server) since it would be of interest

Comment: I'm sorry but I just don't know how many other ways to say that Goldreich's proof is valid and complete. Goldreich proves "If $X \approx Y$ then $X^m \approx Y^m$" -- can you give an example $X$ and $Y$ where you think his proof overlooks something?

Comment: It was stated in the Fischlin and Mittelbach's paper [FM21](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/088): Here is a simple counter example to the above asymptotic version of the hybrid argument. Consider the following sequence $(H_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of “very deterministic” random variables, defined as $H_{i}(\lambda)=1$ if $i\geq\lambda$ otherwise $0$.

Comment: Individually, each of the random variables $H_{i}$ eventually becomes $0$. In fact, for each $i$ the random variables $H_{i}$ and $H_{i+1}$ are computationally and even statistically indistinguishable, because for $\lambda\geq i+2$ both variables only return $0$. If one now takes $t(\lambda):= \lambda$, then $H_{0}$ and $H_{t}$ would be indistinguishable as well, although $H_{0}(\lambda)=0$ and $H_{\lambda}(\lambda)=1$ are trivial to distinguish.

Comment: @kodlu, Fischlin and Mittelbach have a paper in ePrint Archive already. I've asked this question to understand this contradiction between two proofs. I need someone knowledgeable to explain it.

Comment: But that $H_i$ is not a useful sequence of hybrids for proving $m$-fold repetition, right? We don't have $H_0 = X^m$ and $H_m = Y^m$, so what does this "counterexample" have to do with proving $X^m \approx Y^m$? Why should Goldreich need to consider this kind of $H_i$? He (implicitly) introduced a different hybrid sequence with $H_i = (X, \ldots, X, Y, \ldots, Y)$ and (correctly) reasoned about it. Note that I asked you for an example of $X$ and $Y$ such that Goldreich's proof overlooks something about $X^m\approx Y^m$, not an example of an arbitrary hybrid sequence. Do you see the difference?

Comment: It seems Goldreich's proof uses a kind of [circularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning): "...Because the total number of hybrids is polynomial in $n$, a non-negligible gap between (the “accepting” probability of $D$ on) the extreme hybrids translates into a non-negligible gap between (the “accepting” probability of $D$ on) a pair of neighboring hybrids. ...". Goldreich uses this argument in his proof. *The above counterexample in the paper is related to this part, isn't it*? In the paper, before using hybrid argument to prove the theorem, they feel we need some conditions.

Comment: He states this as intuition, and maybe he's not aware of the ways this intuition can fail, who knows? It doesn't matter, though, because he then constructs a reduction algorithm that chooses the hybrid index $i$ uniformly -- exactly what Fischlin and Mittelbach say you should do. Goldreich can use this technique because his proof only considers specific hybrids that have a "transformation algorithm", in the language of F&M.

Comment: Do you appreciate the distinction between the following: (A) "if for all $i$, $H_i \approx H_{i+1}$ then $H_0 \approx H_{\text{poly}(\lambda)}$; vs (B) "if $X \approx Y$ then $X^{\text{poly}(\lambda)} \approx Y^{\text{poly}(\lambda)}$ ?? (A) is not always true. (B) is a very special case of (A) where the hybrids are all "nice" -- they are all of the form $(X,\ldots,X,Y,\ldots,Y)$. (B) is always true, for all $X$. The F&M counterexample $H_i$'s don't look anything like the hybrids used in (B). Goldreich only proves (B).

Comment: @Mikero it's written in the paper (page 9 and 10) "... **Our goal** is to provide a formal proof for this intuition. To this end, let us first formalize the statement that we want to prove in this section via the hybrid argument. ..." *Exactly* the thing that Goldreich wanted to prove. *The difference* is Fischlin and Mittelbach are ending up to *first* considering 4 cases, *then* proving the theorem. But Goldreich doesn't consider these case at all, *although they both proving the same theorem*. Isn't it strange? How do you justify it *after looking at the whole paper* not just parts of it?

Comment: I've done my best but this discussion is not productive and I've lost the patience to continue. I hope you're able to resolve your questions to your satisfaction.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanations.

Comment: @Mikero Although there are still several things that are confusing and vague to me, I think you're right. Others also upvoted the answer. Everything written in the above comments was for better understanding the concepts I wanted to use. I hope you didn't feel disheartened and will continue answering other questions on this platform. Best wishes.